# Como apilar elementos con css

Tags: css3

Quiero apilar los elementos uno encima de otro, pero no logro.

```css
.vertical{
display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical">
  <span>
   uno
  </span>
  <span>
    <a href="#" (click)="getUser(usuario.login)">  dos </a>  
     </span>
     
     <span>
       <a href="#" (click)="getUser(usuario.login)">  tres </a>  
     </span>
    <div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Añade el `display:block` a los `span`, que son los hijos, actualmente solo lo tiene el padre con la clase `vertical`

```css
.vertical{
  display:block;
}
.vertical span{
  display : block;
  border : 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical">
  <span>
    uno
  </span>
  <span>
    <a href="#" (click)="getUser(usuario.login)">  dos </a>  
  </span>

  <span>
    <a href="#" (click)="getUser(usuario.login)">  tres </a>  
  </span>
<div>
```